# Writing Excel sheet using Apache POI from a json array

Tags: java, json, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to pull 5 pieces of json data and write them to an excel sheet. I'm converting the data to a jsonarray and then writing to excel using POI. For some reason, the program is currently only writing the 5th data piece to the first row, and not doing anything with the others. It should be looping through all 5 and putting each in the row it corresponds with. Any ideas?

```
private void sendPost() {
    int rowNumber = 1;

        while (rowNumber < 5 ) {
try {
String id = censusIdValue(rowNumber);
    String url = "https://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/analyze/jun2014/summary/population/censusplace/ids/" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8") + "?format=json";
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    String result = getStringFromInputStream(is);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result.toString()); 
    JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Results"); 
      int rowCount = 0;
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
      XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("wow");

            JSONObject rec = data.getJSONObject(0);
            String geographyId = rec.getString("geographyId");
            String strStatusType = rec.getString("geographyName");
            int numberOfWirelineProvidersEquals0 = rec.getInt("numberOfWirelineProvidersEquals0");

            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            XSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
            cell1.setCellValue(geographyId);
            XSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
            cell2.setCellValue(strStatusType);
            XSSFCell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
            cell3.setCellValue(numberOfWirelineProvidersEquals0);

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("data.xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }


} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    rowNumber++;

        }
}
```

Comment: You should loop on your jsonarray to write all the lines in your sheet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're overwriting the file with each row.  Try putting the write outside the loop.

Also, get rid of the `rowCount` variable.  You want to use your `rowNumber` variable there.

Finally, I think you're only looping 4 times.  (You indicate you want 5 in your question.)

Comment: rowNumber is for another part of the program, but thanks for bringing my attention to it! The problem was I needed to move "int rowCount = 0" outside the loop because it just kept resetting so no new rows were being created.